# Regression with mostly binary and categorical variables in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression, research-design

I am looking to run regression using a variety of  predictor variables: Chemical exposure (1 or 0) - variety of chemicals but all are binary predictors, Illness diagnosis (1 or 0), and TBI severity (0 1 2 3, while controlling for education, age,sex, military rank etc.

Overall, I am trying to predict the outcome on the response score (# of correct answers) for various psychological test.

I am a bit confused on how I should set up my regression model given that I have a combination of categorical and continuous variables to predict  continuous response. I'm thinking of using a glm model in R, but I am not exactly sure what family to use and how to view it graphical since most responses are binary.

Thoughts/Help is greatly appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: Trying to use predictors: Chemical exposure, Illness diagnosis, TBI severity --> all of which are categorical variables   to look at response: # of correct answers  --> which is a continuous variable

Comment: An example model includes this:  glm(formula = BNT$TBI ~ BNT$CorrectSpontaneous + BNT$cPTSD + BNT$cMDD + BNT$HxETOH + BNT$HxDrug + BNT$edu)  --> Predict the severity of their TBI given how many answers they got correctly while controlling for PTSD, depression, alcohol/drug use and education; alternatively I can predict the # of correct answers they will get given their TBI severity and controlling for variables above.            Which model would be better and what would be family in model?

Comment: Given that your outcome is count data, have you considered Poisson or Negative Binomial models?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `family=binomial` option of the `glm()` function, and specify the # correct answers and # incorrect answers as the target variable, as described in the documentation for `family`:

> For the binomial and quasibinomial families the response can be specified in one of three ways:
>
> ...
>
> 3. As a two-column integer matrix: the first column gives the number of successes and the second the number of failures.

Here is a very simple example, where I have included two predictor variables, one continuous (`x`) and one binary (`flag`):

```
df <- data.frame(
  trials=c(5, 8, 10, 3, 4),
  successes=c(2, 7, 1, 2, 3),
  x=c(0.8, 3.2, 0.2, 1.0, 1.3),
  flag=c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
)

summary( glm(cbind(successes, trials-successes) ~ x + flag, family=binomial, data=df) )
```

which gives the following output when I run it (R-3.5.1 64-bit):

```
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(successes, trials - successes) ~ x + flag, family = binomial, 
    data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
      1        2        3        4        5  
-0.3732  -0.3753  -0.5558   1.0811   0.4464  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  -1.1402     0.8477  -1.345   0.1786   
x             1.3404     0.5005   2.678   0.0074 **
flag         -0.7803     0.9165  -0.851   0.3946   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 14.011  on 4  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  1.957  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: 17.196

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```